# Is there a collection of all Simpson's Halloween specials?

Tags: the-simpsons

According to Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_%28series%29) there is a DVD that contains episodes from 4 seasons. I'm looking for a DVD that includes all or most of them. It seems there's collections for all different types of Simpsons episodes so I'm surprised I couldn't find one for this. From Wikipedia:

> The Simpsons Treehouse of Horror episodes, also known as The Simpsons
>   Halloween specials, is a series of Halloween specials in the animated
>   series The Simpsons. They each consist of three separate,
>   self-contained segments. These segments usually involve the Simpson
>   family in some horror, ***science fiction***, or supernatural setting.

Screenshot of search results from iTunes for one of the answers: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no DVD collections that collect the entire current run, but [there is one that includes a few](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009N80Z). Oddly, it is not a straight run. It includes a mix of episodes.

There are however, three iTunes collections which currently cover the Treehouse of Horror episodes from seasons 1 through 18. Oddly again, the collections are not in sequential order, and each collection includes a seemingly random mix of seasons.

- [Collection 1](https://itunes.apple.com/us/tv-season/simpsons-treehouse-horror/id333238589)
- [Collection 2](https://itunes.apple.com/us/tv-season/simpsons-treehouse-horror/id396264503)
- [Collection 3](https://itunes.apple.com/us/tv-season/simpsons-treehouse-horror/id563600268)

Comment: Thanks. Seasons up to 19 you say? I wouldn't mind buying them on iTunes but I think there are seasons missing for me. Is iTunes missing Season 4 - Season 19 for you?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts S4 is in the first collection. I did misread though; S1-18 are represented. Collection 2 has a non-episode special bit included.

Comment: OK in my iTunes there are no full seasons of the Simpsons from 4 until 19 but there are seasons 1-3 and 20 onward. I think there is licensing issues. I've added a screenshot to the post. Maybe I'll check the Treehouse of Horror episodes and try to get the iTunes collections.

Comment: Ah, sorry - you were asking about full seasons from 4-19. I'm not sure. I was just looking for the Treehouse episodes.